# index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 while converting large batch of csv to xlsx using xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, xlsx, xlsxwriter

Have a batch of 1k csv files that need converting with some conditions to xlxs. Running a for loop to select csv files and name the xlsx files. The code works fine for the first 5-6 csv to xlsx file conversions. Then get an error message:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

```
   for i in range(client_list_items):
       client = client_list[i]    
       TradeSignals = pd.read_csv(client + '_TradeSignals.csv',header=None)
       os.remove(client + '_TradeSignals.csv')
       TradeSignals.columns = ['idx','idx','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Symbol','TrendSELL','TrendBUY']
       TradeSignals = pd.merge(TradeSignals,sector[['Industry','Symbol','M-CapRank']],on='Symbol', how='left')
       TradeSignals['Buy_Signal'] = (TradeSignals['Low'] < 
       TradeSignals['TrendBUY']) & (TradeSignals['High'] < TradeSignals['TrendSELL'])
       TradeSignals['Sell_Signal'] = (TradeSignals['TrendSELL'] < TradeSignals['High']) & (TradeSignals['TrendBUY'] < TradeSignals['Low'])
       TradeSignals = TradeSignals[((TradeSignals['Buy_Signal'] == True) | ((TradeSignals['Sell_Signal'] == True)))]
       TradeSignals['Trade'] = np.where(TradeSignals['Buy_Signal'], 'Buy', 'Sell')
       TradeSignals = TradeSignals[['Industry','Symbol','Date','Close','M-CapRank','Trade']]
       TradeSignals.sort_values(by=['Industry','M-CapRank'], inplace=True);
       TradeSignals.set_index(['Industry','Symbol'], inplace=True);
       writer = pd.ExcelWriter(client + '_TradeSignal.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')  
       TradeSignals.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')# <----- error midway after a few files are generated(total batch 1k files)

       writer.save()
```

Need to convert the entire batch of 1k csv files to xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. There were a few instances of empty dataframes that was causing the error.